# GWT i18n implementation without changing url

Tags: gwt, gxt

i want to implement the gwt i18n in my application without changing the url of the application. Anybody knows about this?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from specifying the locale via parameters (*queryparam*), you have other methods: *cookie*, *meta* and *useragent*.

1.- **queryparam**: appending to the url query-string the parameter `locale="es"`

2.- **cookie**: Setting a cookie value somehow and reloading the page, in gwt could use this code:

```
  Cookies.setCookie("foo", "nn");
  Window.Location.reload();
```

you need this line in your module file:

```
  <set-configuration-property name="locale.cookie" value="foo"/>
```

3.- **meta**: You have to add a meta tag to your html page:

```
  <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=es">
```

4.- **useragent**: It uses the `navigator.language` javascript property, which normally matches the desktop language selected by the user, you have to enable it though:

```
  <set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent" value="Y"/>
```

You can define the order of how gwt computes the locale setting this property:

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.searchorder" value="queryparam,cookie,meta,useragent"/>
```

You can get more info reading the comments in the [I18N.gwt.xml](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/I18N.gwt.xml) file.

Comment: Is there the possibility to add a 5th custom option? E.g. read the language setting from the session? If so what classes would need to be extended?

Comment: Session is unrelated to gwt in the sense that gwt is browser code, thus is executed in browser. Then you need to link server session with something in the browser, e.g. by setting a cookie when the session is created and reloading the page. At the end anything that is able to use cases #1 #2 #3 once the session is set, then remember to reload the page